# What does the "folder" setting for "orderBy" do in the Google Drive API files list?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

When fetching files using orderBy=folder, what order should I expect to receive them in?  I presumed it would be hierarchical from parents to children but it seems to be rather random.

Doc ref: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

Comment: In the case of ``orderBy=folder``, it is sorted by ID. The order of sort is number, uppercase letter and lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

The docs says it's ascending by default.

> A comma-separated list of sort keys. Valid keys are 'createdTime',
>   'folder', 'modifiedByMeTime', 'modifiedTime', 'name',
>   'quotaBytesUsed', 'recency', 'sharedWithMeTime', 'starred', and
>   'viewedByMeTime'. **Each key sorts ascending by default, but may be
>   reversed with the 'desc' modifier**. Example usage:
>   ?orderBy=folder,modifiedTime desc,name. Please note that there is a
>   current limitation for users with approximately one million files in
>   which the requested sort order is ignored.

This is true as when I tried to [sort it by 'name'](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?orderBy=name&_h=15&), it was indeed in alphabetical order. Not sure how Drive API lists files by '`folder`' category but you can be assured it does use sort.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the orderBy attribute with "folder" and without it.
when I mentioned the "folder", Google Drive paid attention to the folders that exist in the specified directory, but when I didn't use "folder" Google Drive sorted only the files and not the folders.